# Handshake Problem but with Boys and Girls only shaking with themselves

Tags: combinatorics

There are $b$ boys and $g$ girls standing in a circle. Each person standing in the circle shakes hands with the person to their left and the person to their right ONLY if they are of the same gender.

What is the expected number of UNIQUE handshakes?

***My approach:***

Without loss of generality, we label the people from 1 to n. Let $H_1$ be the number of handshakes for the first person in the circle. Let $E[H_i]$ be the expected number of handshakes to the right for the $i^{th}$ person in the circle.

Let $P(H_i=GG)$ be the probability that the first handshake to the right is between two girls

Let $P(H_i=BB)$ be the probability that the first handshake to the right is between two boys

Let $n$ be the total number of people (i.e. $n=b+g$)

This can by multiplying the probabilities by their values:

$$ E[H_1] = P(H_1=GG) * 1 + P(H_1=BB) * 1 + 0 + 0$$

$$ E[H_1] = \frac{g}{n} * \frac{g-1}{n-1} + \frac{b}{n} * \frac{b-1}{n-1}$$

$$ E[H_1] = \frac{(g(g-1))+(b(b-1))}{n(n-1)} $$

And so, through linearity of expectation:

$$ E[H_n] = E[H_1 + H_2 + ... + H_n] = E[H_1] + E[H_2] + ..... + E[H_n] $$

$$ E[H_n] = n E[H_1] = \frac{(g(g-1))+(b(b-1))}{n-1} $$

**Testing this code-wise it seems to be true, here is my python code:**

```
n = 100000

def handshake():
    circle = [randint(0,1) for _ in range(n)]

    handshakes = set()
    for i, person in enumerate(circle):
        ## Handshakes are added as a sorted tuple to avoid duplicates
        if i+1 >= n:  # Wrap Around for last elt
            if circle[0] == person:
                handshakes.add(tuple(sorted([0, i])))
        elif circle[i+1] == person: 
            handshakes.add(tuple(sorted([i, i+1])))

    b = sum(circle)
    g = n - sum(circle)

    E_H = (b*(b-1) + g*(g-1))/(n-1)
    return E_H, len(handshakes)

iterations = 100
for _ in range(iterations):
  avg_diff = 0
  expected, actual = handshake()

  avg_diff += expected-actual

print("Avg Difference is: ", avg_diff/iterations)
```

Leads to:

```
Avg Difference is: 0.029114091140945673
```

with 100,000 people, the fact that there is an avg. difference of 0.03 seems to conclusively determine that I am correct.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Usually, indicator variables are a good way to handle problems like this.

Comment: Can you calculate the probability that, at some particular position in the circle, there is a handshake to the right? (This is a very relevant piece of information)

Comment: @MiloBrandt please see my latest edit

Comment: Your wording is ambiguous. If I have $BGB$, does the middle person shake hands with both? If I have $BGG$, does the middle person shake hands with only the right one? "They are of the same gender" - what is "they", exactly?

Comment: If you have BGB --> No handshakes. BGG --> one handshake (middle with right). GGG --> Two handshakes (middle with left and right). The ambiguity I think is that I should have specified how many UNIQUE handshakes are there?

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is great. I have two notes for improvement.

- You define $H_i$ to be the number of handshakes that person $i$ has with the person on their right; this is good. You just have a notational problem when you then define $P(H_i=G)$ to be the probability that person $i$ is a girl. $H_i$ is a number, and $G$ is a gender, so you cannot have $H_i=G$. I would instead write your equation as
  $$
  E[H_1]=P(\text{persons $1$ and $2$ are both boys})+P(\text{persons $1$ and $2$ are both girls}).
  $$
- You have an algebra error when you add the fractions:
  $$
  \frac{b(b-1)}{n(n-1)}+\frac{g(g-1)}{n(n-1)}=\frac{b(b-1)\color{red}+g(g-1)}{n(n-1)}.
  $$

Comment: Yep. Missed it, but thankfully my code was correct! I have made your suggested changes, thanks!